# How remove links from apacite

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style, apacite

I am unfortunately an absolute beginner with regards to Latex and am currently trying to create a bibliography that corresponds to the `apacite` style, but does not contain any links, since the DOI code is enough for me.

Is there a command that makes the links disappear for my code? I would be very happy if someone could help me in a hurry. Below is my code example, I have inserted appropriate placeholders for the quote and the text and the references are pulled from a `.bib` file.

I've googled a lot already, but only came across descriptions that were so complicated that I couldn't apply them to my simple file.

I would be very pleased to receive an answer! Thank you very much!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}

\title {Demo Bibtex}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Text

\cite{Source}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\bibliography{/Users/Desktop/Latex/Bibtex-File/Bibliography.bib}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any option for turning this off selectively. The following is a bit of  a hack but it works. It redefines the `apacite` URL environment to be empty, and then in that environment only redefines the `\url` command to be empty.  I've also added some code to keep the `doi:` prefix attached to the actual DOI.

This will *not* work if you have online resources that only have URLs and don't have DOIs, since it removes *all* URLs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Landau2007,
    Author = {Landau, Idan},
    Doi = {10.1162/ling.2007.38.3.485},
    Journal = {Linguistic Inquiry},
    Number = {3},
    Pages = {485-483},
    Title = {{EPP} Extensions},
    Volume = {38},
    Year = {2007},
    url = {http://doi.org/10.1162/ling.2007.38.3.485}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewenvironment{APACrefURL}[1][]{}{}
\AtBeginEnvironment{APACrefURL}{\renewcommand{\url}[1]{}}
\renewcommand{\doiprefix}{doi:~\kern-1pt}
\begin{document}
\cite{Landau2007}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! Definitely made my day! :-)

Comment: Does not work anymore.

Comment: @Pagol "does not work" doesn't provide any clue as to what happens. This code definitely (still) works. If you have a new problem, ask a question linking to this question and show an example like this one and the error or unexpected behaviour you get.